# How to iterate over numeric keys from an array in order to make them accessible in a newly created object from the same array?

Tags: php, casting

Consider the below code snippet :

```
<?php
  $obj = (object) array('1' => 'foo');
  var_dump(isset($obj->{'1'})); // outputs 'bool(false)'
  var_dump(key($obj)); // outputs 'int(1)'
?>
```

The output of above code in a web browser is below :

```
bool(false) int(1)
```

You can see from the output that after converting the array `$obj` into an object I'm not able to access the key of an array(i.e.`'1'`) as an object property and it's corresponding value(i.e.`'foo'`)?

How to make them accessible?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the trick rather using typecasting do it with

```
$obj = array('1' => 'foo');
$obj = json_decode(json_encode($obj));    
echo $obj->{'1'};
```

> // it will output 'foo'